# Drag and Drop using HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to make a project of drag and drop feature. There are multiple images on a screen and I want to drag each of them one by one and drop them anywhere on the screen. If anyone can explain me or give the code on how to implement this feature, that would be of great help.

Comment: This is a great starter guide on drag and drop in javascript. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-drag-and-drop-vanilla-js

Answer (score 0):

To make a dynamic drag and drop, you must use Javascript.

```
Take a look at these examples : 
https://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/yNYOXR
```